# need a button to change its text when clicked

Tags: c#, java, android, xml

I am trying to do a simple toggle silent mode app. I got the for dummies book and no luck so far.

What I want to do is when the audio is on I want to change my text on my button to Turn off (using a string). and when pressed I want it to change to another string. But I can't get this thing down right. I have tried several ways so far. Any suggestions ?

```
 package com.example.silentmodetoggle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TSMMainActivity extends Activity {

    //Instantiate an AudioManager to manage the ringer state
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tsmmain);

        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();

        setButtonClickListener();

        //does this even work?
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.string.silence_phone);
    }//onCreate

    private void setButtonClickListener()
    {
        Button toggleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) 
                {   //set to normal mode
                    mAudioManager
                    .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    mAudioManager
                    .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                }

                //now toggle the UI again
                toggleUi();
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent()
    {
        int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
        {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }
    }

    private void toggleUi()
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;

        if (mPhoneIsSilent)
        {
            //i think i should put it here.

            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);
        }
        else
        {
            newPhoneImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
    }

    private void textView(int silencePhone) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tsmmain, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) 
                {   //set to normal mode
                    mAudioManager
                    .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                    ((Button)v).setText("Turn On");
                }
                else
                {
                    mAudioManager
                    .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                    ((Button)v).setText("Turn Off");
                }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I never saw this in the book, i will have to make note of this.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClickListener(View v) the argument v is the button you clicked on. Therefore you can call the method setText(String s) and change the text.

It should be explicitly cast to its type as v is a generic type of View.